# Is there a built in function to get the back half of a strsep()?

Tags: c, substring, strsep

In short, currently the code below outputs: `The substring is AES`. Unfortunately, I'm looking to get the result `The substring is 100`. This is due to the fact that `strsep()` keeps only the first portion of the split, and not the second. Is there a way to make the 2nd portion the one that's kept instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   const char haystack[50] = "SHA1 = 99\nAES = 100";
   const char needle[10] = "Point";
   char *ret;
   char *bonus;
   ret = strstr(haystack, "AES");

   bonus = strsep(&ret, "=");

   printf("The substring is: %s\n", bonus);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: print `ret` instead of `bonus`: `printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);`

Comment: Worked! I had no clue.

Comment: The documentation is very clear how it works: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html

Comment: This is meant to make it convenient to write a loop to process multiple fields separated by a delimiter.  `while ((f = strsep(&ret, ",")) != NULL) process_field(f);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`strsep` function's documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) :

> ```
> char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
> ```
>
> If `*stringp` is NULL, the `strsep()` function returns `NULL` and does
>   nothing else.  Otherwise, this function finds the first token in the
>   string `*stringp`, that is delimited by one of the bytes in the string
>   `delim`.  This token is terminated by overwriting the delimiter with a
>   null byte (`'\0'`), **and `*stringp` is updated to point past the token**.
>   In case no delimiter was found, the token is taken to be the entire
>   string `*stringp`, and `*stringp` is made `NULL`.

So in your program's case you should print `ret` instead of `bonus`:

```
bonus = strsep(&ret, "=");

printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);
```

Since `ret` will point past the token `"="`.